# Does running Office 2010 through Wine add a significant performance overhead?

Tags: wine, performance, microsoft-office

Say you have have a computer with a data sheet similar to this

- CPU: 1.1 GHz Dual-core Intel Celeron Processor 847
- RAM: 2GB
- HDD: 320GB (5400 rpm)

According to the minimum requirements in Windows platforms this machine would be perfectly able to run Excel 2010:

- CPU: 500 MHz
- RAM: 256
- HDD: 2GB

([Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624351%28v=office.14%29.aspx#section7))

But how much would using WINE instead of a native Windows system impact the performance?

Would I still be able to run Excel with the configuration above, even when editing tables with thousands and thousands of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able, but it most likely will not fun. Excel running on Windows with this Hardware should be also quiet slow (at least from what I can imagine). Just give it a try. Alternatives could be LibreOffice Calc in about 95% of all cases.

Comment: Thank you @frlan, once I have the computer I will update the question